# Php cookie redirect

Tags: php, html, redirect, cookies

I'm trying to redirect returning visitors to index.html from default.php by using php and cookies. 

 Can someone help me out with a code to get this to work? I've been searching on Google and I can't find anything that works. 
 
Thanks!

Comment: You'll never *really* know if someone is a returning visitor; me for instance, my browser is set to delete all cookies on shutdown so I'd always be a "new visitor".

Comment: Well, that's their problem. - lol - Most people allow cookies so it isn't a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i have understand, in default.php:

```
if (!isset($_COOKIE["accessCookie"])) {
  setcookie("accessCookie", 'visited', time()+3600);  /* 1 hour */
}
else {
    header('Location: index.html');
}
```

this code check if the cookie "accessCookie" exists: if not, it's the first time the user visit this page, so we create the cookie and then execute the rest of default.php page.

On the second visit we check again for the cookie: this time the cookie exists, so we redirect the user to index.html page

Comment: Thanks, I got an unexpected { on line 2

Comment: you receive this response because the function HEADER (in my code) MUST be insertet before all kind of output, so i suggest you to put these line of code at the top of the page, so no output will be performed before the header() function

Comment: It's at the very top before the opening <html>

Comment: I got it! There was a double <html>